# Sum values recursively in one line

Tags: ruby

I am pretty sure that it can be done in one line using things like map, sum etc. I cannot figure out how exactly, because I just started learning ruby. Could someone help? Thanks

```
 class Something < ApplicationRecord
 def function
    res = items.count
    items.each do |i|
      res += i.function
    end
    res
  end
```

Comment: `items.sum(items.count) { |item| item.function }` I mean, there's an example right in the docs. Although the recursive part seems a little off since `items` doesn't appear to change.

Comment: A link to the docs might be helpful for the OP

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Might be. Or they could use some sort of new-fangled web search technology to find the docs :/

Comment: Very true, but the OP has said that they are new so may not be used to looking at technical documentation, plus it can be difficult to sift when you don't know what you are looking for

Comment: @DaveNewton this won’t work for second and further levels of nesting. OTOH, for deeply nested structures the OP’s code produces the weird result as well :). But it differs from what `sum` produces.

Comment: @mudasobwa if the internals of `function` are replaced with the `sum` statement I don't see why not, although I'm not applying much thought to it.

Comment: @Dave could you answer please so I will mark as correct answer? Anyway it does not work

Comment: Recursion can not be replaced with mapping.

Comment: So there is no simpler way to write it?

Comment: `items.inject(0) { |s, i| s + i.function }`? This is a really peculiar thing to need to write.

Comment: @tadman have you noticed `function` is being called _recursively_?

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah, but it appears to be called on other objects, so it's alright so long as it bottoms out eventually.

Comment: @mudasobwa I actually do not see any recursion here unless we are to assume `items` is a collection of instances of `Something` otherwise we simply have `Something#function` and `WhateverAnItemIs#function`. The only "recursion" I see is in the title

Comment: @hellorails what is an `item` and what does its `function` method look like?

Comment: @mudasobwa What are you talking about? Dave's is clearly properly recursive, as is Naren's which you downvoted.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I was mistaken, yes, when it’s a content of `def function` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to do it recursively and in one line, but you can try something like this:

**edit:**

```
def add(arr)
    return 0 if arr.length == 0
    # if the arr argument is an empty array, return 0.

    arr[0] + add(arr[1..-1])
    # add the first element of the array to the result of calling add
    # on the array minus the first element.
end
```

If you just want to sum an array as concisely as possible, all you need to do is `[1, 2, 3].sum` or `[1,2,3,4].reduce(&:+)`. No recursion needed.

Comment: Considering @Max's solution,
You can as well replace 
`return 0 if arr.length == 0`
With:
`return 0 if arr.size.zero?`

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward oneliner equivalent to yours:

```
  def function
    items.count + items.sum(&:function)
  end
```

Demo (testing it alongside your original):

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :items

  def initialize(items = [])
    self.items = items
  end

  def function
    res = items.count
    items.each do |i|
      res += i.function
    end
    res
  end

  def function2
    items.count + items.sum(&:function2)
  end
end

root = Something.new([
         Something.new,
         Something.new([
           Something.new,
           Something.new([
             Something.new,
             Something.new([
               Something.new
             ])
           ])
         ])
       ])

puts root.function
puts root.function2
```

Prints:

```
7
7
```

---

Another way:

```
  def function
    items.sum { |i| 1 + i.function }
  end
```

By the way, you count all items except for the root item. Is that intentional?
You could count all including the root with this:

```
  def function
    1 + items.sum(&:function)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in one line but this is how you can do this recursively.

```
def add_array(arr)
 return arr.first if arr.length == 1 
 return nil if arr.length < 1
 
 arr.pop + add_arr(arr)
end
```